# Why am I getting a connection timeout error from my Node MariaDB app after deploying on Namecheap? but works fine locally

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb, namecheap

Node MariaDB app fully works on my local server but not when I deploy to Namecheap, what am I doing wrong? The website works on NameCheap, but when I use my app to register a user I get this error:

```
Request Timeout
This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.
```

Chrome dev tools show Status:500, type:document, initiator:other, size:403B, time:5.0min.
I reached out to Namecheap support to check on their servers, and they said their servers are fine, and to check my code. Not sure what to check for if my app works locally. I've set up my database on Namecheap shared hosting and set up environment variables.

I'm not able to see my console.logs to test errors, so tried using the DEBUG=express:* environment variable.
Here's my stderr.log from using DEBUG=express:* :

```
text/plain stderr.log ( ASCII text )
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "x-powered-by" to true
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "etag" to 'weak'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "etag fn" to [Function: generateETag]
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "env" to 'production'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "query parser" to 'extended'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "query parser fn" to [Function: parseExtendedQueryString]
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "subdomain offset" to 2
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "trust proxy" to false
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "trust proxy fn" to [Function: trustNone]
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application booting in production mode
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "view" to [Function: View]
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "views" to '/home/madejnsw/usa-govt-quiz/views'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "jsonp callback name" to 'callback'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "view cache" to true
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router use '/' query
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router use '/' expressInit
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router use '/' <anonymous>
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router use '/' serveStatic
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:application set "view engine" to 'pug'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router use '/' urlencodedParser
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router use '/' session
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router use '/' <anonymous>
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router use '*' <anonymous>
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '*'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/user-login'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/user-login'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/user-login'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/user-login'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/user-login'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/user-login'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route post '/user-login'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route post '/user-login'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/user-register'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/user-register'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/user-register'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/user-register'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/user-register'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/user-register'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route post '/user-register'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route post '/user-register'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/questions'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/questions'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/questions'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/questions'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/questions'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/questions'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/questions'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route post '/questions'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/progress-report'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/progress-report'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/progress-report'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/progress-report'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/progress-report'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route post '/progress-report'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route post '/progress-report'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/delete-progress'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/delete-progress'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/delete-progress'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route get '/delete-progress'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route new '/user-logout'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/user-logout'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:route post '/user-logout'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router use '/' <anonymous>
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router dispatching GET /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router query  : /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router expressInit  : /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router serveStatic  : /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router urlencodedParser  : /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router session  : /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router trim prefix (/) from url /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:router <anonymous> / : /
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:view require "pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:view lookup "index.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:view stat "/home/madejnsw/usa-govt-quiz/views/index.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:55 GMT express:view render "/home/madejnsw/usa-govt-quiz/views/index.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router dispatching GET /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router query  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router expressInit  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router serveStatic  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router urlencodedParser  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router session  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router trim prefix (/images/judicial.jpg) from url /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router <anonymous> /images/judicial.jpg : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:view lookup "404.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:view stat "/home/madejnsw/usa-govt-quiz/views/404.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:29:57 GMT express:view render "/home/madejnsw/usa-govt-quiz/views/404.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router dispatching GET /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router query  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router expressInit  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router serveStatic  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router urlencodedParser  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router session  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router trim prefix (/user-register) from url /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router <anonymous> /user-register : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:view lookup "register_user.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:view stat "/home/madejnsw/usa-govt-quiz/views/register_user.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:view render "/home/madejnsw/usa-govt-quiz/views/register_user.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router dispatching GET /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router query  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router expressInit  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router serveStatic  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router urlencodedParser  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router session  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router trim prefix (/images/judicial.jpg) from url /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router <anonymous> /images/judicial.jpg : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /images/judicial.jpg
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:02 GMT express:view render "/home/madejnsw/usa-govt-quiz/views/404.pug"
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router dispatching POST /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router query  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router expressInit  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router serveStatic  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router urlencodedParser  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router session  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router trim prefix (/user-register) from url /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:30:19 GMT express:router <anonymous> /user-register : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router dispatching POST /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router query  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router expressInit  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router serveStatic  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router urlencodedParser  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router session  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router trim prefix (/user-register) from url /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:32:19 GMT express:router <anonymous> /user-register : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router dispatching POST /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router query  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router expressInit  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router serveStatic  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router urlencodedParser  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router session  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router trim prefix (/user-register) from url /user-register
Thu, 20 Jan 2022 06:34:19 GMT express:router <anonymous> /user-register : /user-register
```

Is there a better way to see errors that I'm missing, this so far has not been helpful.

Here's my main file server.js using MVC sytle:

```
const express = require('express');

const homeController = require('./controllers/home');
const loginController = require('./controllers/login');
const loginUserController = require('./controllers/loginUser');
const newUserController = require('./controllers/newUser');
const storeUserController = require('./controllers/storeUser');
//const storeIPController = require('./controllers/storeIP');
const logoutController = require('./controllers/logout');
const newQuestionController = require('./controllers/newQuestion');
const answerQuestionController = require('./controllers/answerQuestion');
const userProgressController = require('./controllers/userProgress');
const userGradeController = require('./controllers/userGrade');
const retakeTestController = require('./controllers/retakeTest');

const ipMiddleware = require('./middleware/ipMiddleware');
const redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware = require('./middleware/redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware');
const progressCheckMiddleware = require('./middleware/progressCheckMiddleware');
const redirectIfNotAuthenticatedMiddleware = require('./middleware/redirectIfNotAuthenticated');
const getTopScoresMiddleware = require('./middleware/getTopScoresMiddleware');
const clearGradeMiddleware = require('./middleware/clearGradeMiddleware');

const userController = require('./controllers/userController');
const questionsController = require('./controllers/questionsController');
const progressController = require('./controllers/progressController');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const pug = require('pug');
const path = require('path');
//const config = require('./config');//delete this after dotenv setup
require('dotenv').config();
const { handleError, ErrorHandler } = require('./helpers/error');
const flash = require('connect-flash');

var port = process.env.PORT;

// Init App
const app = express();
console.log(process.env.DB_NAME);

let string;
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.date = new Date();
    string = `[${req.date}]: ${req.method} ${req.path}`;
    console.log(string);
    next();
})

// makes public folder accessible(css, and images)
//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));// <-- Don't need this since views is in root folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));//absolute path
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 5000;
}
//app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server started on port: ', port));
app.listen();

//session set up
//bodyParser dependency no longer needed, can change to express.urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const options = {
    /*
    host: config.database.host,
    port: config.database.port,
    user: config.database.user,
    password: config.database.password,
    database: config.database.database
*/
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    multipleStatements: true,
    connectionLimit: 5
};

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

//session saved on server side, cookies on client side
//cookie parser no longer needed with session, function automatically included
//30 min time
global.timer = 1000 * 60 * 30;
app.use(session({
    name: process.env.SESS_NAME,
    secret: process.env.SESS_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: timer
    },
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(flash());

//this will replace var userId
global.loggedIn = null;

// *wildcard(all requests)
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    loggedIn = req.session.userId;
    next();
});

//home main page
app.get('/', ipMiddleware, homeController);

//login user
app.get('/user-login', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginController);
app.post('/user-login', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginUserController);

//register user
app.get('/user-register', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, newUserController);
app.post('/user-register', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, storeUserController);
//app.post('/user-register', storeIPController);

//get test questions
app.get('/questions', redirectIfNotAuthenticatedMiddleware, progressCheckMiddleware, newQuestionController);
app.post('/questions', answerQuestionController);

//Get user progress and grades
app.get('/progress-report', userProgressController);
app.post('/progress-report', getTopScoresMiddleware, userGradeController);

app.get('/delete-progress', clearGradeMiddleware, retakeTestController);

// fire controllers (can eventually delete after everything works)
//userController(app);
//questionsController(app);
//progressController(app);

//log out user
app.post('/user-logout', logoutController);

//404 errors and more
app.use((req, res) => res.render('404'));
```

Here's my storeUserController:

```
//data connection pool
const pool = require('../models/db');
const { handleError, ErrorHandler } = require('../helpers/error');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

//User regeister post
//registerCheck, middleware
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  let user_name;
  let password;
  let email;
  let id;
  let obj;

  user_name = req.body.user_name;
  password = req.body.password;
  let e = req.body.email;
  email = e.toLowerCase();

  req.session.user_name = user_name;
  req.session.password = password;
  req.session.email = email;
  req.session.quiz_id = 1;
  req.session.question_id = 1;


  console.log(req.session)

  //clean up this Promise i converted to Async Await
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    console.log(hashedPassword);

    let sql = `INSERT INTO Govt_profiles (User_Name, Password, Email)
    SELECT ?, ?, ? 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Govt_profiles WHERE Email = ? OR User_Name = ?);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`;

    pool.query(sql, [user_name, hashedPassword, email, email, user_name], (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    })
    .then(rows => {
      id = rows[0].insertId;
      req.session.userId = id;
      req.lastid = id;
      console.log("req.lastid: ", req.lastid);
      if (!req.lastid) {
        req.session.error = new ErrorHandler(404, 'Email or User Name already used');
        res.render('register_user', {
        //err: err (or if same name to this)
        //err
        error: req.session.error
        });
      } else {
        res.redirect('/questions');
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("something err broke: ", err);
    })
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("something broke: ", e);
  }


}
```

I can't seem to figure this out, I would appreciate some help here. Thanks

Comment: Try to create a very simple app that just connects to the database and returns "Hello World" from a table with one text column. If you can get that to work, you'll likely figure out what's not working with your code above. There's too much code to figure out for us here.

Comment: Thanks @kevintechie , that's a good idea.